# Pandas select on multiple columns then replace

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a multiple column select then replace in pandas

df:

```
a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  0  none
0  0  0  1  none
1  0  0  0  none
0  0  0  0  none
```

select where any or all of a, b, c, d are non zero

```
i, j = np.where(df)
s=pd.Series(dict(zip(zip(i, j), 
  df.columns[j]))).reset_index(-1, drop=True)
```

s:

```
0   b
0   c
1   d
2   a
```

Now I want to replace the values in column e by the series:

```
df['e'] = s.values
```

so that e looks like:

e:

```
b, c 
d
a
none
```

But the problem is that the lengths of the series are different to the number of rows in the dataframe.

Any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: Your commend code worked perfectly. I couldn't get the 'duplicate' answer to work. So from that perspective isnt a 100% duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for product with columns names, add [`rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html), last add [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for replace empty strings to `None`:

```
e = df.dot(df.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
df['e'] = np.where(e.astype(bool), e, None)
print (df)
   a  b  c  d     e
0  0  1  1  0  b, c
1  0  0  0  1     d
2  1  0  0  0     a
3  0  0  0  0  None
```

Answer (score 2):

You can locate the 1's and use their locations as boolean indexes into the dataframe columns:

```
df['e'] = (df==1).apply(lambda x: df.columns[x], axis=1)\
                 .str.join(",").replace('','none')
#   a  b  c  d     e
#0  0  1  1  0   b,c
#1  0  0  0  1     d
#2  1  0  0  0     a
#3  0  0  0  0  none
```